# Relaunch WinRT app when suspended

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a personal WinRT app I'm working on, and when the app is suspended, I would like to have it relaunch itself with different launch parameters.

I know you can kind of already do this with toast notifications, but I would like to know if it's possible to do without any user interactions.

Thanks!

Comment: If your app is registered for a protocol, you may be able to call Launcher.LaunchUriAsync when suspending. Not sure if it works, but interfering with the control flow will make users want to stab you in the face anyway...

Comment: If it is for special purposes and you just want to prevent your app from getting closed, I recommend looking into Kiosk Mode.

Comment: I need it for specific/special purposes, but Kiosk Mode doesn't seem like what I need. a protocol handler might do the trick, so I might give it a try if nothing else works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. I never thought of this before. Your only hope would have been to re-launch your application during the suspending event using protocol activation. But what happens is it is not re-launched, it is reactivated while in the suspending state and the activation is denied. You can't delay the re-activation either because all thread schedules are suspended once the app is terminated, too. I tried this in a test app just now and I'm right.

There's also no option with somehow triggering a background task. Though the ApplicationTrigger is coming with Windows 10, the rule still remains that a background task cannot invoke any UI. So, you can't use a background task.

Then I thought about file activation. Then I realized that file activation is identical to protocol activation and the result would be the same, too.

Yes, the idea of using a timed toast or scheduled reminder would sort of work. It would certainly require the user to tap the toast, and if toast were disabled, or the user didn't tap them (they are transient), you are left not running and nothing going to start you.

There is one more thing you can do. Since there isn't a WinRT solution here, remember there's almost always a Win32 solution. There is nothing wrong with a Win32 in-memory app listening for your app to be terminated and starting it again (like by using protocol activation). Your problem is solved unless you are running this on an ARM device - hopefully not.

I talk about protocol activation here:

> http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/10/walkthrough-using-windows-8-custom.html

Best of luck!